# MVC - Issue with users double-clicking Submit button

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a number of pages in my MVC app where the user clicks a Submit button to post a form. Sometimes users will click Submit and since nothing happens immediately, click it again. Therefore, the form submits twice. To prevent this, I have the following JavaScript code:

```
// When the user submits the form, disable the Save button so there is no chance
// the form can get double posted.
$('#form').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

    return true;
});
```

This code disables the Submit button so the user cannot click twice. This works fine. However, if there are client side validation errors on the form, the Submit button gets disabled but the form is never posted, and now the user cannot post the form. Is there a change I can make to the JS code to detect if there were client side validation errors, and, if so, I either don't disable the Submit button, or reenable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery Validate, you can check to see if the form is valid before disabling the button:

```js
$('#form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<button id="subButton" /> <!-- do not use type="submit" because some browsers will automatically send the form -->
```

Javascript:

```
$('#subButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent browser's default behaviour to submit the form
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    doValidation();
});

var pTimeout;
function doValidation() {
ajaxLoader.show(); //lock the screen with ajaxLoader
var form = $('#registerForm');
var isPending = form.validate().pendingRequest !== 0; // find out if there are any pending remote requests ([Remote] attribute on model)
if (isPending) {
    if (typeof pTimeout !== "undefined") {
        clearTimeout(pTimeout);
    }
    pTimeout = setTimeout(doValidation, 200); //do the validation again until there are no pending validation requests
}
var isValid = form.valid(); //have to validate the form itself (because form.Valid() won't work on [Remote] attributes, thats why we need the code above
if (!isPending) {
    ajaxLoader.hide();
    if (isValid) {
        $('#registerForm').submit(); //if there are no pending changes and the form is valid, you can send it
    }
    else {
        $('#subButton').prop('disabled', false); //else we reenable the submit button
    }
}};
```

Answer (score -1):

Switch it around.

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
   // perform error checking
   if (noErrors) {
      $("#form").submit();
   }
   else {
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
   }
});
```

Comment: Whatever you want it to be. You can have a function that checks the values of your inputs, you can use jquery validate, really anything you like. I typically have a checkFormForErrors() function that validates all of my inputs based on custom requirements for each field

Comment: The validation is already being done via MVC and the attributes I put on the various fields. I need to know if the validation passes or fails and then take action accordingly.

Comment: @RandyMinder I would recommend using jQuery Validate and you can simply say $("form").valid()

Comment: @downvoter Can I get a reason? This is a perfectly acceptable solution